# calculate size of detected object in tensorflow detect

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, view, object-detection

i am making an app to detect 91 categories with help of tensorflow api. I want to show the size of the detected object ie. height* width for that i made following changes in my detectoractivity.java
i added,

```
float width = location.width();
          float height = location.height();
          float area = width * height;
          String s = Float.toString(area);
          TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
          editText.setText(s);
```

at line 322.
but it gives an error saying

> - Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*

full code,
**dtetctoractivity.java**

```
public class DetectorActivity extends CameraActivity implements OnImageAvailableListener {
private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();

  // Configuration values for the prepackaged multibox model.
 private static final int MB_INPUT_SIZE = 224;
 private static final int MB_IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
 private static final float MB_IMAGE_STD = 128;
 private static final String MB_INPUT_NAME = "ResizeBilinear";
 private static final String MB_OUTPUT_LOCATIONS_NAME = " 
output_locations/Reshape";
 private static final String MB_OUTPUT_SCORES_NAME = 
"output_scores/Reshape";
 private static final String MB_MODEL_FILE = 
  "file:///android_asset/multibox_model.pb";
 private static final String MB_LOCATION_FILE =
  "file:///android_asset/multibox_location_priors.txt";

 private static final int TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE = 300;
 private static final String TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE =
     "file:///android_asset/ssd_mobilenet_v1_android_export.pb";
 private static final String TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE =
```

"file:///android_asset/coco_labels_list.txt";

```
   // Configuration values for tiny-yolo-voc. Note that the graph is not included with TensorFlow and
   // must be manually placed in the assets/ directory by the user.
 // Graphs and models downloaded from http://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/ may be converted e.g. via
 // DarkFlow (https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow). Sample command:
  // ./flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights -
-savepb --verbalise
 private static final String YOLO_MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/graph-
tiny-yolo-voc.pb";
 private static final int YOLO_INPUT_SIZE = 416;
private static final String YOLO_INPUT_NAME = "input";
 private static final String YOLO_OUTPUT_NAMES = "output";
 private static final int YOLO_BLOCK_SIZE = 32;

 // Which detection model to use: by default uses Tensorflow Object Detection API frozen
 // checkpoints.  Optionally use legacy Multibox (trained using an older
```

version of the API)
    // or YOLO.
     private enum DetectorMode {
    TF_OD_API, MULTIBOX, YOLO;
     }
     private static final DetectorMode MODE = DetectorMode.TF_OD_API;

```
 // Minimum detection confidence to track a detection.
private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API = 0.6f;
private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_MULTIBOX = 0.1f;
 private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_YOLO = 0.25f;

private static final boolean MAINTAIN_ASPECT = MODE == DetectorMode.YOLO;

 private static final Size DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE = new Size(640, 480);

 private static final boolean SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP = false;
 private static final float TEXT_SIZE_DIP = 10;

 private Integer sensorOrientation;

 private Classifier detector;

 private long lastProcessingTimeMs;
 private Bitmap rgbFrameBitmap = null;
 private Bitmap croppedBitmap = null;
 private Bitmap cropCopyBitmap = null;

private boolean computingDetection = false;

 private long timestamp = 0;

 private Matrix frameToCropTransform;
 private Matrix cropToFrameTransform;

 private MultiBoxTracker tracker;

 private byte[] luminanceCopy;

  private BorderedText borderedText;
 @Override
 public void onPreviewSizeChosen(final Size size, final int rotation) {
   final float textSizePx =
       TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, TEXT_SIZE_DIP, 
   getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
   borderedText = new BorderedText(textSizePx);
   borderedText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

  tracker = new MultiBoxTracker(this);

int cropSize = TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE;
if (MODE == DetectorMode.YOLO) {
  detector =
      TensorFlowYoloDetector.create(
          getAssets(),
          YOLO_MODEL_FILE,
          YOLO_INPUT_SIZE,
          YOLO_INPUT_NAME,
          YOLO_OUTPUT_NAMES,
          YOLO_BLOCK_SIZE);
  cropSize = YOLO_INPUT_SIZE;
} else if (MODE == DetectorMode.MULTIBOX) {
  detector =
      TensorFlowMultiBoxDetector.create(
          getAssets(),
          MB_MODEL_FILE,
          MB_LOCATION_FILE,
          MB_IMAGE_MEAN,
          MB_IMAGE_STD,
          MB_INPUT_NAME,
          MB_OUTPUT_LOCATIONS_NAME,
          MB_OUTPUT_SCORES_NAME);
  cropSize = MB_INPUT_SIZE;
} else {
  try {
    detector = TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(
        getAssets(), TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE, TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE, TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE);
    cropSize = TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE;
  } catch (final IOException e) {
    LOGGER.e("Exception initializing classifier!", e);
    Toast toast =
        Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(), "Classifier could not be initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    finish();
  }
}

previewWidth = size.getWidth();
previewHeight = size.getHeight();

sensorOrientation = rotation - getScreenOrientation();
LOGGER.i("Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: %d", sensorOrientation);

LOGGER.i("Initializing at size %dx%d", previewWidth, previewHeight);
rgbFrameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropSize, cropSize, Config.ARGB_8888);

frameToCropTransform =
    ImageUtils.getTransformationMatrix(
        previewWidth, previewHeight,
        cropSize, cropSize,
        sensorOrientation, MAINTAIN_ASPECT);

cropToFrameTransform = new Matrix();
frameToCropTransform.invert(cropToFrameTransform);

trackingOverlay = (OverlayView) findViewById(R.id.tracking_overlay);
trackingOverlay.addCallback(
    new DrawCallback() {
      @Override
      public void drawCallback(final Canvas canvas) {
        tracker.draw(canvas);
        if (isDebug()) {
          tracker.drawDebug(canvas);
        }
      }
    });

addCallback(
    new DrawCallback() {
      @Override
      public void drawCallback(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (!isDebug()) {
          return;
        }
        final Bitmap copy = cropCopyBitmap;
        if (copy == null) {
          return;
        }

        final int backgroundColor = Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        final float scaleFactor = 2;
        matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        matrix.postTranslate(
            canvas.getWidth() - copy.getWidth() * scaleFactor,
            canvas.getHeight() - copy.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
        canvas.drawBitmap(copy, matrix, new Paint());

        final Vector<String> lines = new Vector<String>();
        if (detector != null) {
          final String statString = detector.getStatString();
          final String[] statLines = statString.split("\n");
          for (final String line : statLines) {
            lines.add(line);
          }
        }
        lines.add("");

        lines.add("Frame: " + previewWidth + "x" + previewHeight);
        lines.add("Crop: " + copy.getWidth() + "x" + copy.getHeight());
        lines.add("View: " + canvas.getWidth() + "x" + canvas.getHeight());
        lines.add("Rotation: " + sensorOrientation);
        lines.add("Inference time: " + lastProcessingTimeMs + "ms");
        borderedText.drawLines(canvas, 10, canvas.getHeight() - 10, lines);

      }
    });
```

}

```
OverlayView trackingOverlay;

@Override
 protected void processImage() {
++timestamp;
final long currTimestamp = timestamp;
byte[] originalLuminance = getLuminance();
tracker.onFrame(
    previewWidth,
    previewHeight,
    getLuminanceStride(),
    sensorOrientation,
    originalLuminance,
    timestamp);
trackingOverlay.postInvalidate();

// No mutex needed as this method is not reentrant.
if (computingDetection) {
  readyForNextImage();
  return;
}
computingDetection = true;
LOGGER.i("Preparing image " + currTimestamp + " for detection in bg thread.");

rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);

if (luminanceCopy == null) {
  luminanceCopy = new byte[originalLuminance.length];
}
System.arraycopy(originalLuminance, 0, luminanceCopy, 0, originalLuminance.length);
readyForNextImage();

final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(rgbFrameBitmap, frameToCropTransform, null);
// For examining the actual TF input.
if (SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP) {
  ImageUtils.saveBitmap(croppedBitmap);
}

runInBackground(
    new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        LOGGER.i("Running detection on image " + currTimestamp);
        final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = detector.recognizeImage(croppedBitmap);
        lastProcessingTimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        cropCopyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cropCopyBitmap);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

        float minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;
        switch (MODE) {
          case TF_OD_API:
            minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;
            break;
          case MULTIBOX:
            minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_MULTIBOX;
            break;
          case YOLO:
            minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_YOLO;
            break;
        }

        final List<Classifier.Recognition> mappedRecognitions =
            new LinkedList<Classifier.Recognition>();

        for (final Classifier.Recognition result : results) {
          final RectF location = result.getLocation();
          if (location != null && result.getConfidence() >= minimumConfidence) {
            canvas.drawRect(location, paint);
            float width = location.width();
            float height = location.height();
            float area = width * height;
            String s = Float.toString(area);
            TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
            editText.setText(s);
            cropToFrameTransform.mapRect(location);
            result.setLocation(location);
            mappedRecognitions.add(result);
          }
        }

        tracker.trackResults(mappedRecognitions, luminanceCopy, currTimestamp);
        trackingOverlay.postInvalidate();

        requestRender();
        computingDetection = false;
      }
    });
```

}

```
 @Override
 protected int getLayoutId() {
  return R.layout.camera_connection_fragment_tracking;
```

}

```
 @Override
 protected Size getDesiredPreviewFrameSize() {
return DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE;
```

}

```
 @Override
 public void onSetDebug(final boolean debug) {
detector.enableStatLogging(debug);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you initiated the textview inside the wrong place.Beside that, you should never put this line :

```
TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

inside a loop. Make your variables global : **editText** and **width** then you can implement a button and in the **onClick** method a toast will be shown with the last value given from the for loop.